# UIScrollView with autolayout pure approach

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, autolayout

EDIT: I managed to get it to work, starting from sratch. But i still don't understand why it won't work in another place. I'll check again later. I close the question.

---

i tried to implement what is described [in this blog article](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-autolayout-pure-autolayout-approach-multiple-smaller-views/) and in this [technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) in a xamarin.ios project without success:

I used the same appearance hierarchy and constraints, but i keep having the error 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints'. The problem relies in the 'Container View' whose constraints can not be set to 0 right/bottom spaces of the scrollview without triggering the error. But if these constraints are removed, the 'Container View' has no width/height and the scrollview does't scroll.

Anyone has a working demo project from this blog post ?

Comment: Hi Softlion, I'm struggling to implement a scrollable UIView using mixed-mode, probably because of a Xamarin's bug. Do you mind sharing how you manage to implement the pure mode, at least the constraints part? Thanks!

Comment: Well there is no bug in Xamarin. But there are bugs (or limitations) in iOS. Let me answer in the question.

Comment: I switched all UIScollview into UITableView, and in cells i add all subviews to the contentview, then bind all contraints of subviews to top and left of the contentview only.

Comment: You are right. In fact, there is a bug in the IOS simulator that makes an UIScrollView stop working. Just restarted it and everything is OK!